# Use CSS To Cause Hover On One Object to Affect Another

Tags: html, css

Using pure CSS I want an image to appear when hovering over text:

HTML

```
<h1 id="hover">Hover over me</h1>
<div id="squash">
  <img src="http://askflorine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/temp_quash.jpg" width="100%">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#squash {
  display: none;
}

#hover:hover + #squash {
  display: block;
}
```

This works fine unless I put something in between the `<h1>` and the `<div>`. I know this is because of the CSS selector I am using (`+`). How could I use an event on one tag to cause a change in CSS on another?

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r0ccynkx/)

Comment: do you mean #hover:hover { background-image:url.... } instead of using <img src...> inside a div?

Comment: @Keith I do not believe so. The behavior in the jsfiddle I posted was correct.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wndg7fk3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [General Sibling Selector](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/general-sibling-selector-css-selector/) `~` selector instead of the [Adjacent Sibling Selector](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/adjacent-sibling-selector-css-selector/) `+` selector, like this:

```
#hover:hover ~ #squash {
  display: block;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r0ccynkx/1/)**

You can read more about different CSS sibling selectors [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/contiguous-sibling-selector/).

Comment: Okay. Is there a way to still have it work for say in this case where the image is placed before? https://jsfiddle.net/b5bn5c6u/1/

Comment: Sadly not, there is not such thing as a previous sibling selector. It would have to come after the element. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<h1 id="hover">Hover over me</h1>
<img id="squash" src="http://askflorine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/temp_quash.jpg" width="100%">

#squash {
  display: none;
}

#hover:hover ~ #squash {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what you put in between the 2 parts.  If text encase squash inside the

```
<p> text here
    <div id="squash"...>
    </div>
</p>
```

Then css changes to

```
#hover:hover + p #squash {
```

Comment: That won't work. You can't put a `div` inside a `p`, so the code won't work as expected. Check if your solutions work before posting them.